# How to develop a Central Administration-Feature in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Hallo,

i need to create a feature for the Central Administration in SharePoint 2010, but i do not know how to do that. I have found websites like [SharePoint Tip #26. Do you know “How to create Central Administration feature”?](http://msmvps.com/blogs/laflour/archive/2009/03/19/sharepoint-tip-26-do-you-know-how-to-create-central-administration-feature.aspx) or [SharePoint Central Administration Feature](http://weblogs.asp.net/wesleybakker/archive/2009/01/28/sharepoint-central-administration-feature.aspx), but they refer to SharePoint 2007 and not to SharePoint 2010.

Are there any websites, books, etc. that teach how to create a Central Administration feature in SharePoint 2010 ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating Central Admin pages in SharePoint 2010 works identical to 2007. The main difference is that the IDs for the menu locations (Where the link will be located in central admin) is completely different.

Have a look at my series about [porting a 2007 SharePoint app to 2010](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2010/03/porting-sharepoint-2007-wspbuilder.html). It deals with this topic.

Answer (score 0):

You you can just activate any your features in central admin manually if you like. (If you have deployed your solution also to that web application)

And would that AutoActivateInCentralAdmin be deprecated in 2010?